# Funcionamiento de un right o left en multiples join (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Estoy intentando crear una consulta para una BD de librerias que cumpla los siguientes requisitos: el número de libros escritos por autores y autoras de nacionalidad española que
vivieron en la segunda mitad del siglo XX por editorial, junto con el nombre de la
editorial. Deben aparecer todas las editoriales, incluso si no publicaron a ningún autor de
nacionalidad española.

EL problema es que tengo que hacer tres joins para obtener los datos solicitados y al hacerlo estoy teniendo problemas para quedarme con todas las editoriales incluso si no han publicado para ningun autor español, lo he intentado obtener con un right join pero no parece funcionar...
Esto es lo que tengo, funciona todo salvo que no me devuelve las editoriales con autores nulos:

```
select count(titulo), nombre, editorial
from libro join autor
on libro.autor = autor.codigo
right join edicion 
on edicion.libro = libro.codigo
where nacionalidad = 'Española' and fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01'
group by nombre, editorial
```

Que puede estar fallando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. Por ejemplo, puedes mover las condiciones del `WHERE` dentro de las condiciones de `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT l.titulo), 
        e.nombre, 
        e.editorial
FROM edicion e
LEFT JOIN libro l
    ON e.libro = l.codigo
LEFT JOIN autor a
    ON l.autor = a.codigo
    AND a.nacionalidad = 'Española' 
    AND a.fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01'
GROUP BY e.nombre, 
         e.editorial
;
```

Sí, estoy usando `LEFT JOIN` porque mi cerebro no puede usar `RIGHT JOIN`s por algún motivo.

Otra forma es no usar las condiciones del `JOIN`, y ponerlo dentro de una expresión `CASE`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT  CASE 
                            WHEN a.nacionalidad = 'Española' 
                            AND a.fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01' 
                            THEN l.titulo
                        END), 
        e.nombre, 
        e.editorial
FROM edicion e
LEFT JOIN libro l
    ON e.libro = l.codigo
LEFT JOIN autor a
    ON l.autor = a.codigo
GROUP BY e.nombre, 
         e.editorial
;
```

Otra forma sería haciendo el `JOIN` con una tabla derivada

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT l.titulo), 
        e.nombre, 
        e.editorial
FROM edicion e
LEFT JOIN libro l
    ON e.libro = l.codigo
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM autor
            WHERE a.nacionalidad = 'Española' 
            AND a.fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01') a
    ON l.autor = a.codigo
GROUP BY e.nombre, 
         e.editorial
;
```

En fin, hay más formas, pero creo que éstas son suficientes.

Comment: Cual seria la diferencia en la primera solucion propuesta entre poner las condiciones del where dentro del las condiciones del join y poner un where?. En ocasiones no se si poner los "and" o un where despues de las condiciones de los joins

Comment: @SteveJade Tienes que pensar que al usar un `WHERE`, estás filtrando definitivamente los resultados del dataset. En un `INNER JOIN`, el resultado sería el mismo, ya que entrega resultados siempre y cuando se cumplan todas las condiciones del `JOIN`. Con un `OUTER JOIN`, (`RIGHT JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` o `FULL JOIN`), igual te entrega resultados que no cumplan con las condiciones del join

Answer (score -1):

**LEFT JOIN** te recupera información aun que un campo sea nulo

```
    SELECT count(titulo), nombre, editorial
    FROM libro 
    LEFT JOIN autor ON libro.autor = autor.codigo
    LEFT JOIN edicion ON edicion.libro = libro.codigo
    WHERE nacionalidad = 'Española' AND fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01'
    GROUP BY nombre, editorial
```

o puedes probar para ver que no tengas problemas con el **RIGHT JOIN** pon **INNER JOIN**

```
    SELECT count(titulo), nombre, editorial
    FROM libro 
    LEFT JOIN autor ON libro.autor = autor.codigo
    INNER JOIN edicion ON edicion.libro = libro.codigo
    WHERE nacionalidad = 'Española' AND fecha_nacimiento > '1950-01-01'
    GROUP BY nombre, editorial
```

Comment: En este caso, el resultado sería el mismo que el del op

Comment: Por que? si solo menciona que tiene el problema con el autor

Comment: Porque de cualquier forma estás filtrando los resultados de los autores españoles con esa fecha de nacimiento